# Ionic tab bar changes URL but not rendered page

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I have a tab bar in Ionic React that should display on some pages and not others. I recently upgraded to Ionic React 5.0.7, and since then my tabs have stopped working. Specifically, although clicking on the tabs changes the URLs, it doesn't reliably change the page that's rendered, and instead shows the same page. (For some odd reason, clicking Discover from Profile works, but not vice versa.) Still, console messages from the page I navigate to do appear, even if none of the visual components do. And if I refresh the page, the correct page renders.

I think my code is quite similar to the example [Ionic React Conference App](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-react-conference-app/tree/master/src/pages), so I'm confused what's going on here.

It works properly in @ionic/react and @ionic/react-router version 0.0.10, but not 4.11.10, 5.0.5, or 5.0.7.

TabBar.tsx:

```js
const TabBar: React.FC<TabBarProps> = () =>
    <IonTabs>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
            <Route path="/:tab(discover)" component={Discover} exact />
            <Route path="/:tab(profile)" component={Profile} exact />
            <Route path="/Page3" component={Page3} />
        </IonRouterOutlet>

        <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
            <IonTabButton tab="discover" href="/discover">
                <IonIcon icon={search} />
                <IonLabel>Discover</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
            <IonTabButton tab="profile" href="/profile">
                <IonIcon icon={person} />
                <IonLabel>Profile</IonLabel>
            </IonTabButton>
        </IonTabBar>
    </IonTabs>;

export default TabBar;
```

App.tsx:

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <IonApp>
                <IonReactRouter>
                    <IonRouterOutlet>
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                        <Route path="/" component={TabBar} />
                    </IonRouterOutlet>
                </IonReactRouter>
        </IonApp>
    )
}
```

Comment: did you check conference app with the same lib versions ?

Comment: The conference app uses @ionic/react and @ionic/react-router ^5.0.5, which is one of the versions I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think you are missing the default path for the `TabBar` component

```
<IonRouterOutlet>
   <Route path="/:tab(discover)" component={Discover} exact />
   <Route path="/:tab(profile)" component={Profile} exact />
   <Route path="/Page3" component={Page3} />
   <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/discover" />} />
</IonRouterOutlet>
```

Comment: Why would the default path be necessary? In App.tsx I actually also had `<Route exact path="/" component={Login} />` as the first child of `<IonRouterOutlet>`, but having that didn't make a difference for the functionality of the tab bar.

Comment: did you try it or are you just asking a question? setting the default path at the app level to login shouldn't have any impact on the tabs... let me know happens after you try my suggestion... you currently have no default path set for the tab route... that is what the default path is necessary